# How to validate login form on button click jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to validate login form on button click.When i click on button then its calling javascript function button click,i need to first validate form,required then click button work.`required` not working.I want to validate before `button` click.

```
<form id="loginform" class="form-vertical" method="post">
             <div class="control-group normal_text"> <h3><img src="~/Content/img/logo.png" alt="Logo" /></h3></div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="main_input_box">
                        <span class="add-on bg_lg"><i class="icon-user"> </i></span>
                         <input type="text" id="txtusername" class="form-control required" placeholder="Username" name="username"  required />

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="main_input_box">
                        <span class="add-on bg_ly"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
                        <input type="password" id="txtpassword" class="form-control" name="password"  placeholder="Password" required  />

                        <br />

    <label style="color:red;font-size:15px;display:none;" id="errormsg">Incorrect Username or Password</label>              


                    </div>

                </div>
                </div>

            <div class="form-actions">
                <span class="pull-left"><a href="#" class="flip-link btn btn-info" id="to-recover">Lost password?</a></span>
                <span class="pull-right"><input type="submit" value="Login" id="btnlogin" class="flip-link btn btn-success" /></span>
            </div>
        </form>

     <script type = "text/javascript"  
     src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" > 
      </script>
         <script type = "text/javascript" > 
            $(document).ready(function() {

          $("#btnlogin").click(function () {

            var user = new Object();
            user.Username = $('#txtusername').val();
            user.Password = $('#txtpassword').val();
            if (user != null) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Admin/Login",
                    data: JSON.stringify(user),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (recordcount) {
                        if (recordcount != null) {
                            alert(recordcount);
                            if (recordcount <= 0) {

                  document.getElementById("errormsg").style.display = 'block';

                            }
                            else {

               document.getElementById("errormsg").style.display = 'none';
                            }


                        }
                        else {
                            alert("Something went wrong");
                        }
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }

    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>a</title>
</head>

<body>

    <form id="loginform" class="form-vertical" method="post">
        <div class="control-group normal_text">
            <h3>
                <!-- <img src="~/Content/img/logo.png" alt="Logo" /> -->
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="main_input_box">
                    <span class="add-on bg_lg">
                        <i class="icon-user"> </i>
                    </span>
                    <input type="text" id="txtusername" class="form-control required" placeholder="Username" name="username" required />

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="main_input_box">
                    <span class="add-on bg_ly">
                        <i class="icon-lock"></i>
                    </span>
                    <input type="password" id="txtpassword" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required />

                    <br />

                    <label style="color:red;font-size:15px;display:none;" id="errormsg">Incorrect Username or Password</label>


                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-actions">
            <span class="pull-left">
                <a href="#" class="flip-link btn btn-info" id="to-recover">Lost password?</a>
            </span>
            <span class="pull-right">
                <input type="submit" value="Login" id="btnlogin" class="flip-link btn btn-success" />
            </span>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"> 
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#loginform").submit(function (e) {
                var user = new Object();
                user.Username = $('#txtusername').val();
                user.Password = $('#txtpassword').val();
                if (user != null) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/Admin/Login",
                        data: JSON.stringify(user),
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (recordcount) {
                            if (recordcount != null) {
                                alert(recordcount);
                                if (recordcount <= 0) {

                                    document.getElementById("errormsg").style.display = 'block';

                                }
                                else {

                                    document.getElementById("errormsg").style.display = 'none';
                                }


                            }
                            else {
                                alert("Something went wrong");
                            }
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                }
                debugger
                return false;
                //e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: hi,thanks working but problem is it will go to other page and just show blank page which contains `recordcount` .I want to stay on this page because on wrong username and password i m showing lable ,just show label `block` on wrong username and password,

Comment: if i use this `   $("#btnlogin").click(function (e)` then working fine but validation not works,it also call function if user not enter username and password

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `onFocusOut()` method in textbox, so when you entered the text in the textbox and goes to next textbox, `focusout()` method will call, and in the `focusout()` method, you have to write your validation logic.
For **example**, you can enable your login button, if text entered in the textbox is validated. Otherwise your button remain disabled.

Comment: this is html textbox,not asp.net

Comment: But then also you can use onfocusout() for the textbox.
.
.
<input type="text" id="txtusername" class="form-control required" placeholder="Username" name="username" required /> 
.
.
--jQuery--
.
.
$('txtusername').onfocusout(function(){
//Username matching code
});